# How to create image (or other "read-only" format) from .doc

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, .doc

Anyone know of a way to convert a .doc with mail-merge fields into an image in C#? Basically we want to be able to display a "read-only" version of the document. This can be an image or some other read-only format if anyone can think of one.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommand converting to PDF as we do for every company document going to customers.
There are plenty of libraries for automatic/dynamical PDF generating.

Would that suit your needs?

Comment: No, we're to the point of needing any cut and paste ability eliminated.

Comment: @Jared: Even if you only supply an image, OCR solutions are good enough to get the text back quickly. Suggestion you feedback (strongly) that any technical solution will not guarantee the receiver will not get the text.

Comment: That's known. We're not trying to prevent the really tech savvy, just the not-so-ethical person that knows cut and paste. Right now "read-only" PDFs are being used, but that's very limited.

Comment: The PDFs have to be generated by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend this solution (Aspose Words):

http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.words-for-.net-and-java/default.aspx